# How to replace in a string only where keyword is not inside or in the middle of <a> tags?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace the keyword "site" with "Stack Overflow" in the source string, but it should only replace when the keyword is not inside a HTML `<a>` tag or between `<a>` and `</a>`.

I've searched a lot and unfortunately haven't found a solution yet.

What I want:

`Right now, site is available at <a href="http://www.example.com/site">site.com</a>`

...should replace to...

`Right now, Stack Overflow is available at <a href="http://www.example.com/site">site.com</a>`

Comment: shouldn't it be Right now, Stack Overflow is available at <a href="http://www.example.com/site">Stack Overflow.com</a> ?

Comment: @iani No, the text between the tags should not be altered.

Comment: @MadMarvin FYI my answer wasn't working originally but it's good to go now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use (*SKIP)(*FAIL) technique

Use a regex replacement:

```
/<a.*?<\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)|site/
```

Replace to:

```
Stack Overflow
```

Explanation:

```php
/<a.*?<\/a>   # Matches entire <a> tags
  (*SKIP)(*F) # Bumps to the next position and forces match to fail
 |            # Allows alternation if the first condition does not get matched
  site        # literal character sequence "site"
/x
```

<kbd>[Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pN4zK6/1)</kbd>

Comment: see the demo, its not replaced the site after a tag

Comment: @JasonOOO It does what the OP needs: text between the tags should not be altered.

Answer (score 1):

If the `<a>` tag is always going to be to the right of your text then some parsing and replacing will do the trick.  This will split your string into two strings, replace `site` in the first string, and then put the pieces back together.

```
$string = 'Right now, site is available at <a href="http://www.example.com/site">site.com</a>';
$find   = '<a';
$position = strpos($string, $find);

$strlen = strlen($string);
$string_1 = substr($string, 0, $position);
$string_2 = substr($string, $position,  $strlen); 

$replace_string = str_replace('site','Stack Overflow', $string_1);

$final_string = $replace_string.$string_2;

echo $final_string;
```

Result: `Right now, Stack Overflow is available at <a href="http://www.example.com/site">site.com</a>`

Comment: Nice practical answer, but it is unfortunate to have the constraint of having the tag to the right. With regex this can be worked with without this constraint, at a slight cost of efficiency.

Comment: I agree...however I don't like regex :)

Comment: Thanks @Dan - however the tags are automatically generated depending on the content, which means they could appear anywhere. Appreciate your effort, nonetheless!